# Can SE make tags that block a question from being asked if the tag is used?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, tags, scope

I was thinking recently about how often this site gets questions related to android development that are instantly closed (because they are off-topic). And I thought of how the meta sites require a specific tag before you can post a question.

My idea is to have a tag, such as 'development'. When a user adds that tag and tries to submit the question, it returns an error and explains that development questions are out of scope for this particular SE site.

Is this doable? Is this a good idea? Just thought I'd throw this out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had similar questions like this one on meta before. We already have such a development tag, but it's not really successful in preventing from dev questions pooping up.

[Liam's idea](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1299/440) seems sophisticated but is also complex and not easy to implement. (Also note that it's already possible to blacklist tags).

But all in all I think the "vote close review queue" does the job pretty will. It seldom takes longer then a day, mostly just a few hours, before a development question is closed. I think that's the best we can get atm without doing some fancy stuff that may be not usable along the other sites.

Answer (score 1):

All I can see this doing is having people not use the tags they're not allowed to use. Heck, most programming questions get tagged with [applications](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications) (which has its own sort of issues), not [development](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a brilliant idea, however not all people tag their questions with development...

We could get a bit more complex and make the system learn what tags are mainly associated with closed questions, and then prompt the submitter to check the FAQ, then submit it.

And we could have 'banned' tags that cannot be submitted. Would require some hefty development though, but I have faith in the SE devs :)